# Grails: How to limit the number of children in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, one-to-many, grails-domain-class, grails-constraints

I want to restrict the number of children allowed in a one-to-many relationship between my Grails domain classes, preferably using constraints. The `maxSize` constraint seems to exist for this purpose (the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/MaxSizeConstraint.html) confirms that it is supposed to work on collections as well as strings and arrays).

My constraint is defined as follows:

```
static constraints = {
    children(maxSize: 2)
}
```

However, during testing I found that Grails allows me to add as many children to the parent as I like, completely disregarding this constraint. Am I misunderstanding the documentation regarding the usage of this constraint? If so, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "size" constraint:

```
children(size: 0..2)
```